# Importing SVG in powerpoint with vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to import SVG file in my presentation with the help of below given script, but its importing in all the slides instead of importing in active slide only.

```
Sub InsertLogoOnEveryPage()

Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim sFontName As String
Dim oTop As Single

' font:
sFontName = "Times"

For Each Sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    Debug.Print Sld.Name
    'Insert logo.
    Sld.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\G-Tools\logo\GEP LOGO 2017-01.svg", _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=357, Top:=240

Next Sld

End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
For Each Sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
```

to:

```
Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
```

and delete the *Next Sld* statment near the end.